# Install bootsprap css-4 in angular java maven based project

Tags: java, node.js, angular, maven, npm

I have created angular application java-spring framework as backend.
I am able to successfully build the frontend and backend using maven. I used frontend-maven-plugin to build angular application. I installed the bootstrapcss-4 using:

```
 npm install bootstrap
```

It is working fine. but when I want to build the whole project using mvn clean install I am getting below error.

```
[ERROR] An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js does not exist.
[ERROR] See "C:\Users\TECHME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-JEHEXD\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! syscall spawn
[ERROR] npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
[ERROR] npm ERR! ui@0.0.0 build: ng build
[ERROR] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
[ERROR] npm ERR!
[ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the ui@0.0.0 build script.
[ERROR] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here I also included the pom.xml maven-plugin for frontend-maven-plugin. com.github.eirslett frontend-maven-plugin 1.7.6 install node, npm and angular module in production mode src/main/ui

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
      <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
            <echo>install node, npm and angular module in production mode</echo>
        </tasks>
        <installDirectory>src/main/ui</installDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/ui</workingDirectory>
        
      </configuration>
      <executions>
          <execution>
          <id>install node and npm</id>
          <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>v14.17.4</nodeVersion>
              <npmVersion>6.14.14</npmVersion>
          </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run build --prod</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

while maven build, It is trying to find the jQuery but it was not there in the give location.

Could you please me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed JQuery module from script section in angular.json file then Its start working for me.